# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Samba vs Windows 10 Pro

Tags: networking, server, permissions, samba, authentication

I'm trying to access Samba share using IP address in URL (\\IP_address)from two Windows 10 clients. One physical and one virtual. The physical is on same subnet as Ubuntu server, virtual is Hyper-V guest and on different subnet.

As I try accessing share via \\IP_address I get classic Windows messages like "Windows can't find \\IP_address. Check the spelling and try again" on virtual client and "Windows cannot access \\IP_address, Error code 0x80004005." on physical client.

I've set smbcontrol smbd debug 10 and I'm providing logs.

All I added to smb.conf is:

[share1]
path=/home/bbahes/share1
readonly=no
browsable=yes

I've also added local user smbpasswd -a bbahes.

PS. If I access samba share from Windows Server 2008 or 2012 (both virtual) I get prompt to enter user name and password and then I can access to shares.

Do I have to enable SMB 1.0 for Windows 10.1803?

Thanks for reply!

log.192.168.225.3
https://justpaste.it/72yxf

log.cli1
https://justpaste.it/5cyzp

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. One word. SeLinux.

Edit:
As soon as I entered command "chcon -t samba_share_t /path" I was able to access share.

Comment: This is basically the **accepted answer** or will be in another 24 hours when you are able to accept it by clicking on the gray checkmark beside your answer, so a bit more of an explanation wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

Windows needs 2 backslashes \\ip_adress  to access a network share.
Have you tried that ? not sure if you put 2 backslashes or if it disappeared in the comment...

Comment: Sorry I copied it wrong :)